# Перенос готовых данных QSettings в приложение при установке

Tags: android, qt

Пишу на Qt приложение под android. Существует задача вместе с релизом приложения передать готовый набор данных QSettings, чтобы приложение при первом же запуске уже имело готовые предустановки. Стандартный вариант с дефолтным значением:

```
settings.value("data", defaultData)
```

не подойдет, так как данные относительно сложного характера.

Answer (score 2):

Согласно документации
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsettings.html#details

On Unix systems, in the absence of a standard, many applications (including the KDE applications) use INI text files.
То есть, можно поставлять с готовым ini файликом.

Если же этого не достаточно, можно использовать custom storage format
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsettings.html#registerFormat

В примере рассматривается хранение в xml формате

P.S. Qt одна из самых лучших по документации система.
Не стесняйтесь к ней обращаться :)

Comment: Благодарю за добрый совет прочесать документацию, но я это уже сделал. Мне бы узнать как готовый файлик закинуть в андроид приложение при его установке.
P.S.: On Unix systems, if the file format is NativeFormat, the following files are used by default:

$HOME/.config/MySoft/Star Runner.conf

Comment: Извиняйте, я просто прочитал Ваш вопрос так - "как передать готовый набор данных QSettings, чтобы приложение при первом же запуске уже имело готовые предустановки". Android, при этом, просто признак конкретной ОС, в данном случае Unix.
Если же здесь Вам все понятно, стоит перенести вопрос в топик андроида, изменив его на "как готовый файлик закинуть в андроид приложение при его установке"